# What shark-species is this shark form "Empire of the Sharks" based on?

Tags: character-identification

In Empire of the Sharks, this marvel of Monster-movie-technology appears:

[image]

Is it based on any real shark-species whose existance I totally missed, or is this species a movie-invention?

Please disregard all lights and metal attachments for species ID, of course ;).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By the looks of it, it seems to be based on [goblin shark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goblin_shark).

[image: a close-up of a goblin shark's head, courtesy of Wikipedia]

Comment: Indeed! Today, I learned about a new shark-species ^^.

Comment: @Layna So... are you going to accept the answer, or are you waiting for some other answer?

Comment: Oops! Sorry, I actualyl thought I HAD accepted! Thanks for the heads-up :).